# How can I temporarily disable hot corners when playing games (or other such full-screen apps) on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mouse, fullscreen, games

I use hot corners to lock my screen/start the screensaver.  I've also recently started playing some games on Steam that run in fullscreen on Mavericks.

Unfortunately, since the mouse cursor is used to control movement, use of hot corners basically makes the games unplayable.

Is there an easy way to toggle hot corners on and off before and after playing games in fullscreen?

I used to use [this script](https://gist.github.com/klynch/827581) but it doesn't work on Mavericks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a quite old question, but I stumbled on it looking for the same thing (although on ML). The script looks interesting, but it's a bit far-fetched for me, I was looking for something simpler and preferably without add-ons.

This is what I found and works for me: in the hot corner's pref pane, hold Command, Option, Control and/or Shift after clicking a drop down list of a hot corner and you can add one or any combination of the modifier keys to a hot corner trigger. This way, they only work if and when you hold that(those) key(s) which you probably won't during a game, or any full screen app.

I'm pretty sure this works on all OS X versions.

Comment: +1 Very nice solution thanks.. now to get used to pressing it when i need to  :)

Comment: Just to add. You do not need to use all the keys. You can use just one up to a your own combination of the above mentioned keys.

Comment: System Preferences app → Desktop & Screen Saver → Hot Corners ; see also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320816/what-are-hot-corners-in-macos

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Works wonderfully!