# What are Hot corners in macOS?

Tags: macos, screensaver

I just got a new Mac and while addressing my screen saver I was prompted about hot corners. What are they and how should they be used?

Answer (score 9):

Hot Corners is a feature of macOS that lets you assign instant actions for when you move the mouse pointer to any one of the four corners of your Desktop.

Hot Corners can lead you to pretty powerful workflows using just the mouse cursor, such as:

- Instantly showing/hiding the Dashboard.
- Putting the display to sleep
- Showing the Desktop
- Displaying notifications by opening Notification Center
- Showing/hiding the Launchpad
- Showing/hiding the Mission Control.

The flexibility of doing these tasks without moving your hand from the mouse/trackpad can lead to faster and easier workflows.

[image]

Hot Corners can be configured by going to System Preferences app → Desktop & Screen Saver → Hot Corners... or System Preferences app → Mission Control → Hot Corners....

For more details, go through the Macworld article, [What’s hot about OS X’s Hot Corners](https://www.macworld.com/article/2042242/what-s-hot-about-os-x-s-hot-corners.html).

Comment: tbh they would allow scripting options. Imagine if you could run a script by moving your mouse to corners.